# getting fullpath of text files to be read in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

Well this has been quite an annoying problem which I cannot resolve after dozens of searches on stack and google.

I have an Asp.Net web application, the solution itself has 7 projects, one of which is an MVC project in which a class like the following resides.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Hosting;
namespace MyApp.Notifications
{
    public class CustomEmails
    {
        private readonly string basePath = "C:\\Users\\MyUser\\MyAppName\\";
        //HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~\\MyAppName")
        //Server.MapPath("~")
        //HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath("~");
       //HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath;

       var subject = File.ReadAllText(basePath + "Notifications\\EmailTemplates\\EmailConfirmationEvent_Subject.txt");
  //rest of classes code here
    }
}
```

The only way I can read a text file in a subfolder is to hard code the path, as shown above. As you can see above, I'm trying to programatically retrieve the base path to the application and then prepend it to the files sub path.

As you can see above, in the commented out snippets, I've tried a number of things.

For starters, Server.MapPath is never allowed as its always in red, intellisense offers no remedies and googling doesn't help much other to offer up that Server.MapPath is an IIS method. All those other code snippets return nothing.

What am I doing wrong? Where is the error? Isn't there a standard way this is done so you always get the right base path whether your on a development machine or on the hosts virtual machine?

Per Darin's suggestion the code is updated as follows;

```
 public class EmailEvents
{
   private static readonly string basePath = CustomEmails.GetWebsiteRoot();
   public class EmailAddressVerified : IEventHandler<EmailVerifiedEvent<UserAccount>>
    {
        public void Handle(EmailVerifiedEvent<UserAccount> evt)
        {
            dynamic smtp = new SmtpMessageDelivery();
            var localAppPath =  CustomEmails.GetWebsiteRoot();
            var htmlBody = CustomEmails.GetHtmlEmailMessage(DomainClasses.Enums.EmailType.AccountConfirmation);
            //{ProductionChange} --change the first parameter to false in production
            htmlBody = CustomEmails.FillEmailPlaceholderText(false, htmlBody, evt.Account);
            htmlBody = htmlBody.Replace(CustomEmails.EmailTextPlaceholders.HtmlFileKey, EncryptDecrypt.EncryptQueryString(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));              
            var subject = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(basePath, "Notifications", "EmailTemplates", "EmailConfirmationEvent_Subject.txt"));
            subject = subject.Replace(CustomEmails.EmailTextPlaceholders.ApplicationName, CustomEmails.EmailPlaceholderValues.ApplicationName);

            var msg = new Message { To = evt.Account.Email, Subject = subject, Body = htmlBody };
            smtp.Send(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, basePath is always nothing but localAppPath retrieves the right path. Why does the class level private variable not retrieve the path?

Comment: Make sure your project has reference to 'System.Web' library. After that intellisense should suggest 'using System.Web.Hosting;' for you

Comment: I have that and still all those HostingEnvironment tries return nothing

Comment: `HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/");` will give you the absolute path to the website root. Of course this will only work in an ASP.NET web host. If you try to execute this code outside of an ASP.NET environment such as a unit test for example it is more than obvious that it will return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable that you then later populate at Run-Time with only a get to make it read only and then use Server.MapPath in a property. You can't do this at compile time as in the class declaration as it can't work out what the string const is because Server.MapPath can't resolve into a const that it can use, as its almost certainly alters with deployment.

```
public class CustomEmails
{
    private string _basePath = null;

    private string BasePath 
    {
        get 
        {
             if ( _basePath == null ) 
             {
                 this._basePath = Server.MapPath('...');  
             }
             return _basePath;
        }
    }
```

At run time your first request to this.BasePath will populate the private variable using MapPath (one time call) and then all subsequent calls to the method will use the previously obtained value.

Comment: `Server` is a property of WebForms base class. Your code will never compile because `CustomEmails` doesn't derive from any base class. You should use `HostingEnvironment.MapMath` instead which is a static method.

Comment: @CodeUniquely VS still doesn't like Server in this line  this._basePath = Server.MapPath('...');  as it is red, as it always is when i try to use it

Comment: @Darin  Are you referring to an assembly reference? because i don't find any with that name

Comment: @dinotom, suffice for you to read the documentation in order to know which assembly and namespace you should bring into scope for the HostingEnvironment class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment(v=vs.110).aspx. So as the documentation states assembly: `System.Web.dll` and namespace: `System.Web.Hosting`.

Comment: I have both of those references, as you can see if you read the post. And as noted in the post, HostingEnvironment.MapPath returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`HostingEnvironment.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment(v=vs.110).aspx) static method.

1. Add reference to the `System.Web` assembly
2. Add `using System.Web.Hosting`
3. Write a class with a single method referring to the website root:

   ```
   using System.Web.Hosting;

    namespace MyApp.Notifications
    {
        public class CustomEmails
        {
            public static string GetWebsiteRoot()
            {
                // Get the website root
                return HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/");
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Remark: The `HostingEnvironment.MapPath` will work only inside an ASP.NET webhost. If you attempt to use it outside (such as a unit test or desktop application) it will not return the desired result.

In this case it is much better to have your functions take as dependency the website root path. This will make them easier to unit test. It is only inside the Composition Root that you will use the proper method to inject the path. For an ASP.NET web context that would be the `HostingEnvironment.MapPath` method.

Also when you are dealing with directories paths you totally want to use the [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of the `+` operator which you used in your question. For example:

```
string root = CustomEmails.GetWebsiteRoot();
string path = Path.Combine(root, "Notifications", "EmailTemplates", "EmailConfirmationEvent_Subject.txt");
```

Comment: thank you, I'm getting yanked for dinner. Will test it when I can

Comment: Well I tested it and var basepath = GetWebsiteRoot, using your code is still returning nothing, now im getting yanked for dinner.

Comment: Okay, so now I've tested it a few different ways. It gives a value of nothing, when used as in the post; -- private readonly string basePath = GetWebsiteRoot(); If I add a variable in the method I need it, it does yield the proper path. Why doesn't this work as a private class level variable but does work as local variable in the method? I'd prefer it as class level as I use it in a number of methods.

Comment: any thoughts as to why it works as local variable and not as private class level variable?